# IDA Dalvik Debugger w/ Android Libgame.so file?

Tags: android, debugging, shared-libraries, adb, ida

I am trying to debug and breakpoint a `libgame.so` file that I extracted from an APK. It loads fine, and all the functions appear, but it won't let me use the Dalvik Debugger and attach to my phone like I did with the `classes.dex` file.

**EDIT:** All that appears is: No debugger, Remote ARM Linux/Android Debugger (and GDB) and Trace Replayer. How do I set it to use the Dalvik Debugger if it's not listed?

Comment: The `.dex` files are Dalvik bytecode and the `.so` library files are machine code.  You'll need to use an ARM debugger to debug an `.so` file

Answer (score 0):

Posting my comment as an answer so that this question can be closed:

> The `.dex` files are Dalvik bytecode and the `.so` library files are machine code.

You'll need to use the ARM debugger to debug the `.so` file.